# I cant access this file even after using close() function

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

So I did this and the values of `cars` and `cars1` updates every second

```
    Total=cars+cars1
            count=open('test.txt','w')
            print(Total,file = count)
            count.close()
```

Then I read this `test.txt` file with my php code given below:

```
    <?php
    $file = fopen("test.txt","r");
    
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $content = fgets($file);
        echo "{$content}";
    }
    fclose($file);
    ?>
```

The values get stored, but it is not displayed on the browser when I run the php file.

But if I delete the `test.txt` file and create a new one and add the value manually then it is displayed in the browser.

I dont know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If Python is grabbing that handle every second, how is the PHP script supposed to know when it's available for reading? It's not clear to me how the two processes are interacting in a mutually exclusive way.

Comment: Oh i see so how i can make the php script available for reading.Also the processes are that the python script detects the car using opencv and prints the total number of cars as the car is in the frame,then is use open() funtion to save the output and then display it through php script also saving it into database.THANKYOU!